# How to run EF migrations when deploying to Azure Website via Visual Studio Online

Tags: entity-framework, azure, azure-devops

I have an Azure website configured to deploy from Visual Studio Online (hosted TFS). I'm evaluating the move from *Database First* model to *Code First from Existing Database* model.

Currently, As I check-in code to Visual Studio Online, it is deployed to Azure website. How to configure this process to run EF Migrations on the remote (live or test) Azure SQL database when I check-in code to Visual Studio Online.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, you need to use the publish profile option to achieve this.

You have to download the **publish profile** settings file for the website, Import the file in Visual Studio, configure the **Execute Code First migrations** option and then specify the profile file path in Build Definition used for Continuous deployment.

You can check below post for reference.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/04/09/ef-code-first-migrations-deployment-to-an-azure-cloud-service.aspx

Comment: Thanks for a answer Jehan. I'm aware of this option in Publish tool.
But I'm looking for method using deployments via source control (Visual Studio Online).

Comment: The steps mentioned in my response are for deploying through Visual Studio Online builds using publish option.

Comment: So is there a way to do this with continuous deployment?

Comment: Hey there @DanJosef, I just asked a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35107531/how-can-i-run-entity-frameworks-migrate-exe-from-visual-studio-online

Answer (score 2):

I know it is a old post, but I could't find a good answer, so after figure out how to solve it I'm sharing a solution. I work in a project with DDD and N-tiers level. So, it means that the EF isn't in the same project as WebApi, therefore has no option to run migration during the publish wizard. To solve it I have ran update-database directly from package manager console.

Steps:

1. Acquire the ADO connection string (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-connectivity-issues/#connections-to-azure-sql-database)
2. From package manager console run: `Update-database -StartUpProjectName NAMEPROJECTWITHEF -ConnectionString "connection string obtained from item one" -ConnectionProviderName "System.Data.SqlClient"`

That's all!

Best Regards,
thiago