# How can I run Entity Framework's migrate.exe from Visual Studio Online?

Tags: entity-framework, azure-devops

I have set up continuous integration for my project with `Visual Studio Online` build definitions.

When it comes to deploying my database (to an Azure test environment) I just build my `SQL Server Database Project` with the right publishing settings.

But I want to switch to `Entity Framework`'s code first approach and leverage the migration feature, which requires me to call migrate.exe.

My question is - how could I run migrate.exe from `VSO` build definitions?

Comment: Which build system are you using? vNext or XAML?

Comment: I'm using vNext. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you are using vNext build, add a "Nuget Installer" task in your build definition first to restore the Entity Framework during the build. Migrate.exe will be installed in \packages\EntityFramework.\tools folder. Then add a "Command Line" task to run the migrate.exe. Enter “\packages\EntityFramework.\tools\migrate.exe" in "Tool" area and the arguments in "Arguments" field.

Comment: As I know, wildcards cannot be used in Command Line task. So how to remove dependence from EF version?

Comment: i'm getting the following error.  Any ideas? Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0  Running on vNext build system.

Comment: @TWilly Refer to this link for how to use the migrate.exe: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-sg/data/jj618307.aspx

Answer (score 10):

We've succesfully implemented an automated EF code first migration at deploy time on top of TFS Build vNext in the following way:

It basically involves 3 steps (per EF-context):

1. Copy EF-project to a staging directory
2. Copy migrate.exe in same folder (**migrate.exe requires to be placed right next to assembly containing EF migrations**)
3. Execute migrate.exe

In detail:

1. Copy Files "task"

   - Source folder: $(build.sourcesdirectory)
   - Contents: Contoso.EF\bin\debug\ **
   - Target folder: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/EF
2. Copy Files "task"

   - Source folder: $(build.sourcesDirectory)\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools
   - Contents: migrate.exe
   - Target folder: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\EF\Contoso.EF\bin\debug\bin\debug
3. Batch script "task"

   - Path: $(build.sourcesdirectory)_Deploy\MigrateEFContext.bat
   - Arguments: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\EF\Contoso.EF\bin\debug Contoso.EF.dll [SQL-SERVER-INSTANCE] [DbName] System.Data.SqlClient

The MigrateEFContext.bat file assembles the migrate.exe-command with its arguments:

```
SET EFDir=%1
SET EFContext=%2
SET connStringDataSource=%3
SET connStringInitialCatalog=%4
SET connectionProviderName=%5

%EFDIR%\migrate.exe %EFContext% /ConnectionString:"Data Source=%connStringDataSource%;Initial Catalog=%connStringInitialCatalog%;Integrated Security=true" /connectionProviderName:%connectionProviderName% /verbose
```

Comment: Does the same applies to Azure DevOps or is there an easier way nowadays?

Comment: @Albert: Same, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

You can also look at executing your migrations at App startup time.

add the following to your Application_Start() event in global.asax

```
var configuration = new Configuration();
var migrator = new DbMigrator(configuration);
migrator.Update();
```

This will fire the migrations at each application startup.  you could also wrap with conditional logic to control how it is fired.

Comment: Yup. As described here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2014/04/08/ef-code-first-migrations-deployment-to-an-azure-cloud-service/

Comment: I believe this to be a very dangerous approach as you won't know about migration issues until the first call to your website. I would certainly advocate a specific upgrade step to the database as an explicit step.