# TFS VNext Build and Entity Framework Migrations - Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online)

Tags: entity-framework, azure, azure-devops, tfsbuild

I'm building a .Net app using Entity Framework.

I have TFS vNext Builds setup and I'm doing auto publish to an azure web app.

I'd like to add a build task to automate my entity framework changes.

I'm using code first and have migrations enabled, so I need a task that will run my migrations during the build to make any database schema changes, and seed test data that needs to be added/updated to the database.

Essentially I'd like to get the process used by ReadyRoll
http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/readyroll/
Without having to spend $350 per licence.

Comment: awww, man. who down voted this? isn't this a legit question?

Comment: If you sign up to the webinar (July 28th), there's a decent chance of winning a free ReadyRoll license. https://attendee.gotowebinar.com/register/8806722376847083521

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install [EntityFramework](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/6.1.3) nuget package to your project. And then restore the nuget package and call "migrate.exe" in the package folder to run the migration. Refer to this question for details: [How can I run Entity Framework's migrate.exe from Visual Studio Online?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35107531/how-can-i-run-entity-frameworks-migrate-exe-from-visual-studio-online)