# EF Code First Migration with Migration.exe in Visual Studio Online [Release]

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

**Overview:**

I am working on 
**ASP.NET MVC Project with Entity Framework's Code First**
 approach for the database.

I recently automated the deployment process via **VSO pipelines (Build & Release**)

**Problem:**

1. For Application Deployment it's perfect and working fine.
2. For Database I am facing issues (explained below).

**Details:**

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35107531/how-can-i-run-entity-frameworks-migrate-exe-from-visual-studio-online), [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/04/09/ef-code-first-migrations-deployment-to-an-azure-cloud-service.aspx) and [this](https://www.benday.com/2016/11/07/using-tfs-build-to-deploy-entity-framework-database-migrations-with-migrate-exe/) but issues in these solutions are

1. They are using Publish Profile setting, which would run the migration on application start event, which I don't want (not a best practice though)
2. For others using Build Pipeline (copying (a) EF tools, (b) Dll's and (c) run migrate.exe via command line to run update-database command), and it will eventually run migrations on Successful Build. I rather want it to deploy changes on 'Successful Release'.

**My Work**

I moved step (c) from build to release pipeline. But it's not able to find the drop.

Secondly, How to roll back in case of a crash on production?

Can anyone suggest what the best approach to solving this scenario?

Comment: What do you mean "But it's not able to find the drop."? What error did you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of crash on production, you can rollback database to previous version by running `update-database -TargetMigration:"Migration_Name"`

Comment: i know, but In release pipeline HOW?